# WebMatrix site missing some folder?

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix

I have installed Microsoft WebMatrix from this site [Install WebMatrix](http://www.asp.net/web-pages) ,But when i open it and click "create Empty Site" then it just create a site, but there is no folder (like **App_Data, bin, default.cshtml**) present in the site. I am using Microsoft VS 2008. I don't know what i am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Empty Site for Asp.Net Web Pages is created selecting the Empty Site Template from the Template Gallery